# Hardware Keyboard

Tags: android

My application makes heavy use of ListViews. I find that Landscape mode significantly hinders the functionality of it. I was thinking I would lock the orientation to portrait mode. However, I have 2 text inputs (launched in alert dialogs) to consider. Neither inputs will be accessed every time the app is used, typical usage would probably be about 30% of the time.

The first text input will typically be 6-12 characters. Even if you have a hard keyboard, it might not be worth it to use it here. I thought I might even automatically pop up the soft keyboard to save the user a click.

The second text input is up to 255 characters, something that if you have a hardware keyboard, you might use. But if the orientation is locked to portrait and you have a side sliding keyboard, it'll be awkward.

Any ideas on how to handle this for maximum functionality?

Comment: It's not good practice to set your application to use only portrait orientation. Some device mostly tables have default orientation landscape so your lists will be with the wrong orientation.

Comment: Don't forget that on some devices like the motorola charm, the default orientation is landscape. Portrait makes app unbearable to use.

Comment: -1, because I hate programmers that limit the layout decisions of the users. Typical examples are windows programs, where the programmer felt that it is best run maximized, so on every invokation the d.... thing maximizes.

Comment: @Ingo - calm down. I asked how to handle this because I feel that the functionality of what my app does is significantly hindered in landscape mode. I don't see a way around it, long lists with short words don't work well in landscape.    So do I make a really functional app for most phones or a less functional app that works with every android device past present and future? I'm trying to find a middle.

Comment: +1 to offset ingo.  While I agree with his general sentiment, limiting the layout decisions of other programmers is an even worse crime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design call.

Just weight pros and cons and make a choice, i would go for the lock and using a virtual keyboard. I think is where it's all heading and that they have nothing to envy to a good old hardware keyboard, but some people still loves them, although the lists get all fuzzy and the UI gets awkward.